# "Push" Notifications to user

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, push-notification

I need to know the best way to notify a user of a new notification. I'm looking for:
When an event occurs on server, the specific client(s) are notified and client JS calls a function.
Almost like the pusher service, but on my own server. Is there a way I can do that with AJAX or WebSockets or another service?

Comment: What sort of event?  What technology are you using at the server-side?

Comment: Windows with IIS and Node.JS, PHP, MySQL etc.

Comment: http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/

Comment: http://nowjs.com/examples/notification

Answer (score 1):

Since [you said that you're using Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457784/push-notifications-to-user/10457821#comment13505226_10457784): [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) or [nowjs](http://nowjs.com/).

Comment: this for sure are great methods if you're using node.js. For other technologies go have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Coding

Websockets are of course very neat but not yet supported by all browsers. What could work then is _Long Polling_.